# Como somar todos os elementos de um ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-repeat

Exemplo: Tenho um ng-repeat qualquer, que repete cada um um número. Como faço para armazenar uma variável que seja igual à soma deste número de cada repeat?

Código AngularJS:

```html
ngular.module('meumodulo', [])

.controller('mercadoria', function($rootScope, $http) {

    var ctrl = this;
    $rootScope.listademercadoria = [];
    
    $rootScope.mercadoria0 = {
        id: 'id1',
        setor: 'setor1',
        foto: 'foto1',
        descr: 'descr1',
        de: de1,
        por: por1,
        mercadoria: '0',
        quantidade: 1,
        total: ''
    }

    $rootScope.listademercadoria.push($rootScope.mercadoria0);

    $rootScope.mercadoria1 = {
        id: 'id2',
        setor: 'setor2',
        foto: 'foto2',
        descr: 'descr2',
        de: 'de2',
        por: 'por2',
        mercadoria: '1',
        quantidade: 1,
        total: ''
    }
    $rootScope.listademercadoria.push($rootScope.mercadoria1);



    $rootScope.showPanel = true;
    $rootScope.listademercadoria.push($rootScope.mercadoria1);

    $rootScope.remover = function(b) {

        {
            $rootScope.showPanel = !$rootScope.showPanel;
        }
    }


});
```

Código HTML:

```html
...

<div class="body" ng-controller="mercadoria">
  <span>Total dos produtos: {{listademercadoria[0]['total']}}</span>
</div>

...
```

Estes códigos mostram apenas o valor da variável "total" dentro de $rootScope.mercadoria0.

É preciso que mostre a soma das variáveis "total" de todos os repeats que houverem, mesmo que seja inserido no futuro mais mercadorias, como mercadoria2, mercadoria3, mecadoria4, então o total teria que se alterar conforme o número de mercadorias inseridas.

Já pesquisei muito, mas em tudo o que vejo, parece que seria necessário inserir, a cada mercadoria nova, uma nova parcela na soma. Ex: `{{listademercadoria[0]['total']}}+{{listademercadoria[1]['total']}}+{{listademercadoria[2]['total']}}` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guilherme,

Não é recomendado utilizar **$rootScope**, pois ele é uma variável global. Utilize somente quando necessário. *(e.g. usar um $rootScope que salva a sua página anterior e sua atual, para criar um botão de "Voltar" inteligente)*
Utilize no lugar o **$scope**.

Eu fiz da forma que faria e montei um Plunker para facilitar a visualização do seu problema: [Clique Aqui](https://plnkr.co/edit/JOcCcwi7VH3mBBgstaVu?p=preview)

Básicamente criar uma variável **totalSum** e atribui ela em um laço loop **For**

**controller.js**

```
$scope.totalSum = 0

for(var i = 0 ; i < $rootScope.listademercadoria.length; i++){
       $scope.totalSum = $scope.totalSum +  
       $rootScope.listademercadoria[i].quantidade
}
```

**index.html**

```
<span>Total dos produtos: {{totalSum}}</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma função que retorna a soma executada no `controller`. Note que fiz isso no exemplo abaixo com a função `somar`:

```js
angular
  .module('meumodulo',[])
  .controller('MercadoriaCarrinhoController', MercadoriaCarrinhoController);

MercadoriaCarrinhoController.$inject = [];

function MercadoriaCarrinhoController(){
  var vm = this;

  vm.somar = _somar;

  _iniciar();

  function _iniciar() {
    vm.listaDoCarrinho = [];

    vm.listaDoCarrinho.push({
      id: 'id',
      setor: 'setor',
      foto: 'foto',
      descr: 'descr',
      de: 'de',
      por: 'por',
      mercadoria: '0',
      quantidade: 0,
      total: 5,
      boto: -1
    });

    vm.listaDoCarrinho.push({
      id: 'id2',
      setor: 'setor2',
      foto: 'foto2',
      descr: 'descr2',
      de: 'de2',
      por: 'por2',
      mercadoria: '1',
      quantidade: 1,
      total: 0
    });
  }

  function _somar() {
    var tamanho = vm.listaDoCarrinho.length;
    var soma = 0;

    for (var indice = 0; indice < tamanho; indice++) {
      soma = soma + vm.listaDoCarrinho[indice].total;
    }

    return soma;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="meumodulo">
  <div ng-controller="MercadoriaCarrinhoController as vm">
    Total: {{vm.somar()}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Observação:** O ideal é que sua propriedade `total` seja declarada sem aspas, afinal é um número e não uma `String`.